# Any tool that helps me do housekeeping on backups folder

Tags: backup, 17.10, data-recovery, rsync, tar

Is there a tool or script I can use on a folder with a bunch of files. Files are added to this folder almost hourly. The tool should be "housekeeping":

- Leave all files timestamped within the last 24 hours
- Leave some (n) files that's a month old
- Leave some (n) files that's an year old
- Delete the rest

( n can be 1 for now for the sake of simplicity )

The idea is, when a data corruption/loss happens, I can go back to

- a state (any available) from the last 24 hours
- a state (if available) from 1 month ago
- a state (if available) from 1 year ago

Comment: Don't know a tool but the find command with the `mtime` option will be useful in this case.

Comment: Since you have specific demands I would say: create your own script for this. I would do this: copy files you want to keep to another directory and remove the files in the default backup directory.  Oh I would do that manually though for the backup for the month and year and leave the daily backup as is. Then again: in my opinion a month old backup or older is generally useless.  And why not store ALL backups on-line (ie. google drive)? Plenty of room there. I have a mounted location on google drive where I drop my files and there are backupped online.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on which tool you are using for your backups. Many backups have configuration where you can specify what is to kept how long. Most backup tools do differential or incremental backups so that singular backup files aged 1 month or 1 year are useless.

Comment: I actually want to use simple bash if possible. No I'm not using special "backup tools" and prefer not to :)

Comment: So you want to basically re-implement Duplicity from scratch?

Comment: wow duplicity looks interesting

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the tip by Andrea, duplicity might be designed to address needs closer to mine.
From http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html
(the last command looks promising):

> Here is an example of a backup, using sftp to back up /home/me to some_dir on the other.host machine:
>
> ```
>     duplicity /home/me sftp://uid@other.host/some_dir
> ```
>
> If the above is run repeatedly, the first will be a full backup, and subsequent ones will be incremental. To force a full backup, use the *full* action:
>
> ```
>     duplicity full /home/me sftp://uid@other.host/some_dir
> ```
>
> or enforcing a full every other time via *--full-if-older-than* <time> , e.g. a full every month:
>
> ```
>     duplicity --full-if-older-than 1M /home/me/sftp://uid@other.host/some_dir
> ```

Upate: Today I found this interesting article
http://www.tarsnap.com/helper-scripts.html
I believe what I'm trying to achieve is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme#Grandfather-father-son
The article lists some tools.
Update2: This script is interesting https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/backups-shellscripts-rotation.html